# Generate YAML file from string with SnakeYaml

Tags: java, snakeyaml

Is it possible to parse with snakeyaml the following content (String)

> environments.dev.url:http://dev.examle.com
>
> environments.dev.name:Developer Setup
>
> environments.prod.url:http://another.example.com
>
> environments.prod.name:My Cool All

and obtain a YAML file

```
environments:
dev:
    url: http://dev.example.com
    name: Developer Setup
prod:
    url: http://another.example.com
    name: My Cool App
```

Comment: Your output looks like a YAML file, how does that differ from yuml (which seem nothing to have to do with yUML)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SnakeYaml does not provide in built functionality to parse/convert a given .properties file into .yaml file.

You can try some third party libraries to convert your properties file into yaml file.

[properties-to-yaml](https://github.com/aclement/properties-to-yaml)

[props2yaml](https://github.com/Codearte/props2yaml)